# How to pause and resume javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to pause the javascript code below after it calls $('#dialog').dialog('open'); and until user responds this dialog box. I used while loop but it stops all the javascript. I just want to pause this function. Any ideas?

**Note: I dont want to split my code into two functions. I just want to pause javascript until the user enters some values, like a prompt**

```
function sendSubComment(button){
form = button.parentNode
nodes= form.elements;
cmt = $(nodes.item(0)).val();
cmt = cmt.replace(/\n/g,"<br>");
title = $(nodes.item(1)).val();
for(i=0;i < nodes.length;i++){
    nodes.item(i).disabled = 'true';
}
c = form.parentNode.parentNode;
if(checkUserLogin() == false){
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
     //pause starts here
     //return the values of user
     //resume javascript
}
document.title = c.id;
$.post('index/phplibrary/action.php',{cmd:'insert_comment',cmt:cmt,title:title,id_topic:<?php echo $GLOBALS['id_topic']; ?>,id_parentComment:c.id,subcomment:'1'},function(result){
        $.post('ajax/comments.php?cmd=get_subcomment&id_subcomment='+result,function(res){
                extendMakeComment(form);

                node = c.childNodes[3];
                document.title = node.className;
                t = document.createElement("DIV");
                t.innerHTML = res;
                t = t.childNodes[0];
                $(t).hide();        
                node.appendChild(t);
                $(t).show("slow");
                form.reset();
                for(i=0;i < nodes.length;i++){
                    nodes.item(i).disabled = '';
                }
            });

    });
```

}

this code is how i create dialog box

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
autoOpen: false,
width: 600,
buttons: {
    "Ok": function() { 
        $(this).dialog("close"); 
    }, 
    "Cancel": function() { 
        $(this).dialog("close"); 
    } 
}
});
```

Comment: although it's too late.. but for new readers.. i use.. window.prompt("message",returnvaruable); it will pause/stop all javascript in background and when you hit.. ok or cancel from these prompt, it will let the javascript continue.

Answer (score 3):

Your going about it the wrong way if you want to "pause" the execution of the javascript while you wait for a response from the user.

You should open the dialog box when the user requests it (Clicks a button, or on page load, etc). Then when the user fills out the info on the dialog box and submits it, have it call another javascript action to process that data.

Some psuedo code below:

Page loads:

```
$(".DialogBox").show();
```

When the DialogBox OK button is clicked

```
$(".DialogBox input[type=submit]").click(function(){
   // Process the data
});
```

Comment: Funny, two upvotes for this and one downvote for mine .. which suggests the same thing!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pausing, just contain the rest of the code in a function that you call when the dialog information is submitted:

```
if(checkUserLogin() == false){
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    $('#dialog').find('.classOfSubmitButton').click(function(e){
      loginCode();
    }
} else {
    loginCode();
}

function loginCode() {
    // everything after resume javascript comment
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using events are probably the way to go.

```
function sendSubComment(button){
  if(checkUserLogin() == false){
    $( "#dialog" ).bind( "dialogclose", function(event, ui) {
      if(checkUserLogin() == true) //this check is needed to eliminate dead loop
         sendSubComment(button); //call again
      $( "#dialog" ).unbind(event, ui);
    }).dialog('open');
    return; //not going further
  }
  //do the other stuffs
}
```

Comment: nothing is happened; no dialog box is displayed. What are those bind and unbind for? Can they cause problem?

Comment: maybe because you checkUserLogin() does not return true or false but undefined instead. see http://jsbin.com/ijovo4/edit#preview

Answer (score -1):

alert ("Press OK to continue"); ?

Answer (score -1):

You're talking about a *modal* [jQuery dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog), which must be dealt with before the user can proceed with any other GUI elements.

```
$('#dialog').dialog("option", "modal", true);
// ^ it would be best to set this when you
// _create_ the dialog, but this works too

$('#dialog').dialog('open');
```

Comment: can you help more it doesn't work on me i'll edt the question and add how i create the dialog box

Comment: It blocks the UI but it doesnt block the underlying javascript.

Comment: @exculuber: "it doesn't work" isn't particularly useful. Describe _precisely_ what you see, and how it differs from what you want to see.

Comment: @Tomalak regardless of whether it's a good thing or not, it doesn't answer his question.

Comment: @ajbeaven: The original question clearly stated that he didn't want to pause "all Javascript". It did also say that he wanted to pause "just this function"; the solution is to set the proper callbacks on the dialog. Blocking the UI is the solution: blocking the underlying Javascript is neither a good idea, nor what the OP really wanted.